# Force click highlights button but doesn't click it? - Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am attempting to click on a button.

`element.click()` was not consistently clicking, so I tried to force a click `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`. However, my force click doesn't click the button, but only highlights the borders of the button.

I suspected that perhaps the button was a dynamic element. But I tried accounting for that in my `xpath`.`element.click()` isn't consistent enough to use, but force click doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

I couldn't find any information about why a force click might not work, besides a dynamic element. Any ideas what might be going on?

```
driver.get("https://bi.prozorro.org/sense/app/fba3f2f2-cf55-40a0-a79f-b74f5ce947c2/sheet/HbXjQep/state/analysis")

element=WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//th[@tid='st.header']//span[@title='Учасник']//following::th[@tid='st.header.search']")))

#element.click()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior? You're clikcing on a table cell, this might be how the event handle works. Tough to tell without any html or site link.

Comment: The site link is included in my ```driver.get``` code! That ```element.click()``` works (sometimes) but the force click doesn't makes me think that the expected behavior should be a click

Comment: weird, your xpath doesn't appear in the dom for me at all. I'm not sure I can help you. Sorry. But click() should work just as well as your JS version.